# Not able to use "number_with_precision" in ApplicationHelper's method in Rails 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using "number_with_precision" method in Rails View, it is working fine there, for example:

**In Rails View:** (works fine)

```
<%= number_with_precision(job.company.rating, :precision => 2) %>
```

But when I try to do the same in ApplicationHelper's method then it gives me the following error:

> undefined method `number_with_precision' rails

Here is what I have tried:

**In Rails ApplicationHelper:** (gives error)

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def employer_overall_rating(overall_rating)
      @overall_rating = number_with_precision(overall_rating, :precision => 2)
  end

end
```

How can I use the same in ApplicationHelper?

Comment: `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` in your application_helper.rb ?

Comment: Try `helper.number_with_precision(overall_rating, :precision => 2)`

Comment: @孙悟空 i wish if you have posted this as an Answer, so that i could accept this, anyways thanks alot :)

Comment: @孙悟空 Please post the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` in your application_helper.rb

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to clutter the namespace with number helpers, one way of doing that is calling the helper through `ActionController::Base.helpers`.

```
def employer_overall_rating(overall_rating)
  @overall_rating = ActionController::Base.helpers.number_with_precision(overall_rating, :precision => 2)
end
```

Naturally that would be simplified by:

```
def helpers
  ActionController::Base.helpers
end
```

Then you could do just `helpers.number_with_precision`

Another way is to include `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`

Answer (score 2):

Try Following

```
module ApplicationHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
    def employer_overall_rating(overall_rating)
      @overall_rating = number_with_precision(overall_rating, :precision => 2)
    end
end
```